# How to edit VSCode settings? ctrl + s DOES NOT WORK with React

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have problems with CTRL + S command,it creates empty lines and does not saves the content as expexted with React code. It seems that I should edit my settings.json file

When i try to edit
[image]

It says
Unable to write into user settings. Please open the user settings to correct errors/warnings in it and try again.

This is how user settings look like

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
   "source.organizeImports": true,
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true,
    "source.fixAll": true
  },
  "window.zoomLevel": 1,
  "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
  "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "eslint.codeActionsOnSave.mode": "all",
  "debug.javascript.autoAttachFilter": "always",
  "cSpell.userWords": [
    "addcomment",
    "loggedin"
  ],
  "javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterSemicolonInForStatements": false,
  "editor.rulers": [
    "editor.formatOnPaste": false,
    "editor.formatOnSAve": false
  ]
```

What should  I change?

Answer (score 0):

The config.json file must contain one object - yours contains a few. Try wrapping the whole thing in `{}`.